# Python Selenium How to Run Continuously?

Tags: python, selenium, while-loop, selenium-chromedriver, try-catch

I want to my program start again when `driver2.find_element("xpath", f'//*[text()="{entry1.get()}"]').click()` gives error how can i do it pls help me

```
class a(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        bot()
        while True:
            bot()

    def bot():
    global driver2
    global chrome_options2
    options2 = {
        'proxy': {
            'http': random.choice(proxylist),
        }
    }
   
    chrome_options2 = uc.ChromeOptions()
   
    driver2 = uc.Chrome(
        options=chrome_options2,
        seleniumwire_options=options2,
        use_subprocess=True,
    )
    url = 'https://www.google.com'
    again = True
    while again:
        try:
            driver2.get(url)
            driver2.find_element("name", "q")
            time.sleep(1)
            driver2.find_element("name", "q").send_keys(entry.get())
            time.sleep(1)
            driver2.find_element("name", "q").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            time.sleep(1)
            driver2.find_element("xpath", f'//*[text()="{entry1.get()}"]').click()
            again = False
        except:
            pass
    time.sleep(5)
    driver2.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 800);")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver2.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, -800);")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver2.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 800);")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver2.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, -800);")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver2.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 800);")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver2.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, -800);")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver2.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the code block you want to repeat until it succeed inside `try-except` block inside `while` loop. As following:

```py
url = 'https://www.google.com'
again = True
while again:
    try:
        driver2.get(url)
        driver2.find_element("name", "q")
        time.sleep(1)
        driver2.find_element("name", "q").send_keys(entry.get())
        time.sleep(1)
        driver2.find_element("name", "q").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(1)
        driver2.find_element("xpath", f'//*[text()="{entry1.get()}"]').click()
        again = False
    except:
        driver2.close()
time.sleep(5)
driver2.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 800);")
time.sleep(1)
driver2.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, -800);")
time.sleep(1)
driver2.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 800);")
time.sleep(1)
driver2.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, -800);")
time.sleep(1)
driver2.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 800);")
time.sleep(1)
driver2.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, -800);")
time.sleep(1)
driver2.quit()
```

Your code should be improved. It's not a right way to set a hardcoded delay of 1 second after each code step.

Comment: thank you soo muuch but when its true opened new chrome page and selenium doesnt work and i want to restart chrome in 2 options because i change proxy every time. Thank you againnn

Comment: I don't understand you, pardon. Does this resolved your problem or still not? If no - what exactly is the problem?

Comment: your code works but does not close the current page and opens a new chrome tab and opened 2 chrome tabs and doesnt response new chrome tab it waiting on main page and dont searhing google . I want it to close the page and start new page my program opens new chrome tab i want only work 1 page. Sorry for my bad english. Thanks for helping.  i share my full code my first post

Comment: OK, if I understand you, all you missing is to close the tab in case `click()` not worked and leave it only when it worked correctly so we can continue with that tab? If so you just need to put `driver2.quit()` inside the `except:` block.

Comment: Thank youu but chrome tab closing but doesnt re open again how can i fix it. Thanks againnn

Comment: It should re-open the browser at the beginning of `try` block. When you see the browser not reopened? On what step?

Comment: it doesnt give error just waiting

Comment: Again. On what step?

Comment: started with debugging mode and it works in first time and go to the driver.quit in except block and it goes again while block and its  go to driver.get(url) after that it jumps except blog i think doesnt work in try block

Comment: Ah, I think I know... We should change `driver2.quit()` with `driver2.close()`. Please let me know it that resolved the problem. Changing the answer accordingly

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id    now give this error

Comment: Strange... Need to debug this, but I have no time for that now. I'm sorry